# Can I set multiple Static Roots in django?

Tags: django

My problem:

I already have a static folder for .css .js and images. But I have another directory in my server that stores recorded video, which keeps populating on a daily basis. I want django to be able to access files from that directory, where the videos keep populating. What can be the solution to this? Is it possible to make multiple static roots?

Comment: 1) sound like that is a `media` folder, not `static` because they're not **static** but _populated on daily basis_; static files are a part of a project sources and are supposed to be renewed within a **release** process, not **data edit** 2) take into account that Django has nothing to do with serving neither static, nor media files on prod - it's a job for Nginx or similar web server 3) urls are not the same as folders they can look differently no matter how you serve them - map whatever url pattern to whatever folder and this will work

Comment: okay..so how do I map url pattern to a folder?

Comment: Like you did for static folder in your nginx conf.

Answer (score 2):

with STATICFILES_DIRS you can take multiple paths:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)
```

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Thank you Sajad. Your answer is very useful ;)

Comment: @MiladHatami Thanks for having my back dear friend <3